# Create sObject dynamically

Tags: apex, account, static-resources

I ve tried this script to create accounts from excel file and it works,but if this file had more fields ,I would have to store their values one by one.Is there a way to do this mapping using something like acc.put(fieldname,value) inside a loop?.

```
            String[] filelines = new String[]{};
            List<Account> accstoupload;
            StaticResource srObject = [select id,body from StaticResource 
            Where Name = 'AccountUploadTemplate'];
            String contents = srObject.body.toString();


            filelines = contents.split('\n');


            accstoupload = new List<Account>();
            for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
            {
                String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
                inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

                Account a = new Account();
                a.Name = inputvalues[0];
                a.ShippingStreet = inputvalues[1];       
                a.ShippingCity = inputvalues[2];
                a.ShippingState = inputvalues[3];
                a.ShippingPostalCode = inputvalues[4];
                a.ShippingCountry = inputvalues[5];

                accstoupload.add(a);
            }
     insert accstoupload;
```

Comment: `I would have to store their values one by one` - what do you mean by this?

Comment: what i meant was that file to create account records has 6 columns,each colum represents a field,in the script i had to store those field values one by one(a.Name = inputvalues[0]; a.ShippingStreet = inputvalues[1]; , and so on),its no big deal.But if the file had 30 colums, it would be kind of a problem,thats why i ve been loking for something generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put exact field API names in the header of excel which will be `0` index. Collect the fieldNames and the do as following (will work for any number of fields):

```
    filelines = contents.split('\n');
    accstoupload = new List<Account>();

    String[] fieldNames = filelines[0].split(',');
    for (Integer i=1, linesCnt=filelines.size() ; i<linesCnt ; i++) {
        String[] inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
        Account newAccount = new Account();
        for(Integer c=0, fCount=fieldNames.size() ; c<fCount ; c++) {
            newAccount.put(fieldNames[c],inputvalues[c]);
        }

        accstoupload.add(newAccount);
    }
    insert accstoupload;
```

Comment: I see,problem is I must use the field names in the file

Comment: Yes, exact field names so that they are mapped correctly as per account objects

Comment: why is it a problem, in any case you will 1st row as field names?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. You can go through [sObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) salesforce documentation wherein you can search for `put` method which serves your purpose.

```
public Object put(String fieldName, Object value)
```

So, if you want to create an Account object dynamically and set its value dynamically, you can probably store the mapping of the `csv column label` with the field names, object names, data type etc in custom settings or custom metadata and then use this custom setting data to set the values of `sObject` using `put` method of `sObject` class.

Here is an example where custom setting holds the mapping between `Account` object's API names with its corresponding column name in CSV file

```
//here you can have a key as the csv column header name
//if you have multiple objects, then you can create a unique key and then get the data object wise
//and use the map to get all fields
Map<String_dataset_name, CustomSettingName__c> mcs = CustomSettingName__c.getAll();

filelines = contents.split('\n');
for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
{
    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

    sObject acc = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').newSObject();
    for(CustomSettingName__c cs : mcs.values()){
        acc.put(mcs.get(cs.csvColumnName__c).fieldAPIName__c,inputvalues[cs.csvColumnName__c]);
    }
    accstoupload.add(a);
}
```

Comment: While you are correct, I do not see any improvement on the original situation.

Comment: @FlorianHeer Well I answered the basic question of whether it is possible to create sObject dynamically and set its values. Anyhow, I updated the answer with the possible approach. Hope that helps the OP

Answer (score 0):

Store the name of the field API's which are in the header, in a list. Make sure the name of the field in the header are field API name.

```
filelines = contents.split('\n');
List<String> fieldNames = filelines[0].split(',');

for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
{
    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

    Account a = new Account();

    for(Integer data=0;data<inputvalues.size();data++)
    {
        String api = fieldNames[data];
        String value = inputvalues[data];
        a.put(api, value);
    }

    accstoupload.add(a);
}
```